# loading screen when window opening up: Android

Tags: android, titanium

i am using the Titanium studio for developing android application. a user click on item a **new window** is being opened which fetch data from a site and populate the tableview. so this window does take time to open.
mean while i am fetching the data and showing loading screen like:

```
anotherWind.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
      activityIndicator.show();

      setTimeout(function(){
    e.source.close();
    activityIndicator.hide();
  }, 6000);
});
```

the problem is at this point i'm assuming it takes **6 second**  to fetch and display a tableview. but in real time it may not be the case as time may vary depending upon the data

when user click a icon it should display the loading screen only for the time data is not pulated and showed in tableview.

*its a kind of notification between two tasks. one when task is complted it should notify other one*.
how can i resolve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom event listener. 
Example:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('tableDataLoaded', function() {
     activityIndicator.hide();
}
```

When your table data is loaded, you fire the event:

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('tableDataLoaded');
```

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems multi-thread will be a good solution.Android provide some mechanisms of communication between different threads or processes.

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented the same. my new window needs to load remote data and populate the tableview.

so i just show the indicator in window open

`anotherWind.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
      activityIndicator.show();
});`

and then hide it when my remote data is loaded. inside the callback of httpclient

```
'APIGetRequest(this.apiURL, function(e) {
    var status = this.status;
    if (status == 200) {
              populatetableview(this.responseText);
              activityIndicator.hide();
             }
```

});'